# how to fit buttons size in Button Toggle Group

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, material-components

My design contains a button group which choices, example:
[image]

I want to achieve this buttons being stretched equally to the width of a `Button` Toggle Group like here on the photo:
[image]

I tried to add `ConstraintLayout` inside  Button Toggle Group, but it didn't work, I have no any ideas left. Help me with this, here is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/button_group"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_one"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bachelor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_center"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Master" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_three"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Doctoral" />

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this using the `android:layout_weight` attribute on all the buttons, and a width of `0dp` to apply the weight:

```
<Button
    ....
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Apply the same to the rest of buttons.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]